# Inserting PHP code in Perl with html template

Tags: php, perl

got code from sponsor and it is in PHP , sadly my website is written in Perl and have html templates , when i try to paste code script just don't work...I'm realy noob in coding maybe You guys can help me? Here is code :

```
   <?php
   // Replace the download URL.
   $download_url = "<TMPL_VAR direct_link>";
   // Replace the software name to appear in the installer.
   $software_name = "PUZZLE";
   // URL to a logo image. Must be configured through your affiliate manager.(Optional)
   $logo_image = "http://cdn.airdlrstatic.com/graphics/affiliate/yourname/image.png";
   // URL to a product image. Please consult your affiliate manager for details.
   $product_image = "";
   // Sub ID (Optional)
   $sub_id = "";
   // Software Bundle ID for tracking.
   $bundle = "c8d494949";
   ?>

   <a href='<?php include '/download/download.php'; ?>'>Click Here!</a>
```

Any solutions to this ?

Comment: Well… er… yes. PHP is not Perl. You cannot mix and match them.

Comment: Include PHP in Perl - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455369/can-you-include-php-in-a-perl-file

Answer (score 3):

Put the `PHP` code in a `PHP` file and then add an `iframe` in the page your want it displayed.

Say you call your php file `myfile.php` and in the web page you want it displayed you add the following code:

```
<iframe src="myfile.php" width="300" height="400" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

There are other (better) ways obviously, but require some coding skills. This is the easiest way you can achieve it without any complex coding.

Comment: +1, though I think there should also be another option to open the frame in another window. Some browsers don't support `iframe`.