# Can I pass variable from Perl to PHP and backwards?

Tags: php, perl

I was asked to write a plugin for Foswiki in Perl, and I found complete code of my task in PHP (huge amount of code). What I wanted is to write simple plugin in Perl which is passing String variable to PHP script, PHP script will process it and return the result, and I want to pass it to Perl and thats it :)

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/455453
Someone described a solution to "catch" a result from PHP, but I still need passing string to PHP. Is this even possible?

Comment: As noted in one of the answers you link to above, you can pass command line arguments when calling php from your perl script.  
There is also the possibility of using something like wget to save a url (potentially with GET parameters as in `http://example.com/?q=<somequery>`) to a file and then parsing that file for the information you need

Comment: Good idea :) I was thinking about something different. How about this: PERL script is passing string variable to .txt file, and calling PHP script, then PHP is reading .txt and take this string, then process it and echo the result. Then in Perl Script in my $output = `php test.php`; like in the link above I will have my result. What do you think?

Comment: yes, that can also work. It could also be interesting for you to look at [curl](http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.17/lib/WWW/Curl.pm) And/or you might even build a small API for the PHP webapp that would allow you to have more flexibility

Comment: How about some other forms of IPC?  As in pipes or shm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a variable per say (since that refers to memory in one process), but there numerous ways of passing information from one program to another. Here's one:

First program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );
my $request = "abc";
my $reply = capturex('upper', $request);
print("$request => $reply\n");
```

Second program (`upper`):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php echo(strtoupper($argv[1])) ?>
```

Comment: I did it like in the link I posted in the question. In php: echo "PHP generated this"; and in perl: my $output = `php test.php`; so perl generates a .txt file and put there a string, then with $output = `php test.php`; I call php script that reads the .txt file, process it, and return a result with echo which I "catch" with $output. For me it was the easiest way :) Thx all!