# How to use a Perl code inside a php code

Tags: php, perl, cross-language

I have this Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WordNet::QueryData;
use WordNet::Similarity::random;
use WordNet::Similarity::path;
use WordNet::Similarity::wup;
use WordNet::Similarity::lch;
use WordNet::Similarity::jcn;
use WordNet::Similarity::res;
use WordNet::Similarity::lin;
use WordNet::Similarity::hso;
use WordNet::Similarity::lesk;
use WordNet::Similarity::vector; 
use WordNet::Similarity::vector_pairs; 

#loading wordnet
my $wn = WordNet::QueryData->new;
my $path = WordNet::Similarity::path->new($wn, "config-files/config-path.conf");
my $value = $path->getRelatedness("eat#v#1", "play#v#1");
print "PATH Similarity = $value\n";
```

This script computes the path similarity between the two verbs (eat , play) using the Wordnet ontology.
I want to use this script inside my php code but I don't want to use exec(),system(),shell_exec() functions to call the perl script.
So my question: is there any way to use this perl script inside my php code directly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438626/calling-perl-script-from-php-and-passing-in-variables-while-also-using-variabli --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455369/can-you-include-php-in-a-perl-file

Comment: Well, there is no production worthy solution that I can think of. But if you just want to fiddle with it, then configure apache to process .pl scripts with perl, and run curl requests to and from your script.

Comment: Why don't you want to use any of those functions?

Comment: [When you're ready to do the opposite ...](https://metacpan.org/pod/PHP)

Comment: @mob FWIW: That module doesn't work with any modern version of PHP.

Comment: @Barmar Actually I want to compute the similarity for a big number of word pairs, so if I used those functions there will be too much I/O traffic between php side and Perl side and that's taking too much time (13 seconds for 2000 pairs)

Comment: Are you sure communication is the bottleneck? Maybe you're not doing it efficiently. Are you restarting the script for each pair? You could start the perl script as a coprocess, send word pairs to it through a pipe, and receive the responses through another pipe. Make sure you disable buffering to prevent deadlock.